# Finding a DFA for concatenation

Tags: finite-automata

Consider a deterministic finite automaton $M(k) = (Q, Σ, \delta, 0, F)$, with $k ≥ 2$ and

$Q = \{0,1,...,k-1\}$

$Σ = \{0,1\}$

$\delta(q,a) = (q+a) \space mod \space k$

$F = \{0\}$

If $L$ is the language recognised by $M(k)$, describe a deterministic finite automaton
that recognises the concatenation $L ⋅ L ⋅ L ⋅ L ⋅ L ⋅ L ⋅ L$

Is there a way of doing it without converting it into 7 NFAs, joined by epsilon transitions, and then converting that back into a DFA using the power set construction?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a trick question. $L^7 = L$, so you already have a DFA for it.

The words in $L$ are those where the symbol $1$ occurs a multiple of $k$ times. If you concatenate seven of them, the total number of $1$ symbols is still a multiple of $k$. So $L^7 \subseteq L$. On the other hand, $\epsilon \in L$, so you have $L \subseteq L^7$ because for a word in $L$, you can just add six $\epsilon$ to it.

Comment: But epsilon transitions aren't possible in DFAs?

Comment: @SVMteamsTool I'm not talking about epsilon transitions. I'm not talking about the DFA at all there. This is just about the language.

Answer (score 2):

It would be the case that $L = L^i$, for $i \ge 1$ (in your case $i=7$).

Say you have a DFA $M_i$ for $L^i$. We prove that $w$ is accepted by $M_i$  if and only if $w$ is accepted by $M$.

- **If $w$ is accepted by $M_i$ then $w$ is accepted by $M$.** Observe that once a string is accepted by $M$, $M$ must be at the start state. Now, it must be that $w$ can be divided into $i$ substrings,  where each substring can be accepted by $M$. When $w$ is given as input to $M$, we can think of it as if $M$ is consuming each substring then reseting back to the start state.
- **If $w$ is accepted by $M$ then $w$ is accepted by $M_i$.** Since the start state of your DFA is also the final state, it accepts the empty string. Think of $w$ as if it is divided into $i$ substrings where the first substring is $w$ itself and the rest are empty strings.

Comment: > When w is given as input to M, we can think of it as if M is consuming each substring then reseting back to the start state.

How would this be implemented with a DFA

Comment: >  Think of w as if it is divided into i substrings where the first substring is w itself and the rest are empty strings.

But DFAs don't have epsilon transitions?

Comment: For your first comment, note that the resetting is already in the DFA you gave. Take a look at your transition function, when the DFA is at state $k-1$ and the input is 1, then the new state is $((k-1)+1) \mod k = 0$, which brings the DFA back to 0, the start state, hence resetting. What I am trying to say here is that the DFA for $L^i$ is also $M$, the DFA for $L$

Comment: As for the second comment, you do not need an $\epsilon$ transition. A DFA does not change state when given an $\epsilon$ string. So what it means is that after consuming $w$, $M$ will be at the start state (also the final) and it will remain there.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the same DFA given for $L$ also accepts the language $L^7$ because $L=L^7$.  Note that while a DFA $M$ can accept many strings, it accepts only one language, called the language accepted by $M$, and denoted $L(M)$. It was possible for the given DFA to accept both $L$ and $L^7$ because these two languages are the same. Both $L$ and $L^7$ are subsets of $\{0,1\}^*$, so the equality in $L=L^7$ refers to set-theoretic equality.

For concreteness, we can work out the solution for $k=3$; the same solution method works for arbitrary $k$.

Let the machine $M$ be the DFA that has three states $q_0, q_1, q_2$. The start state is $q_0$ and the set of final states is $\{q_0\}$.  There are three transitions with label $1$: a transition from $q_0$ to $q_1$, a transition from $q_1$ to $q_2$, and a transition from $q_2$ to $q_0$.  This completes a directed cycle of length $3$.  Draw a transition from each state to itself with label $0$.  Observe that when you start at state $q_0$, go around to the next state in the cycle for each input symbol $1$, and return to the starting point, the number of $1$'s in the input string would have been a multiple of $3$.  Thus, you can convince yourself that the language $L:=L(M)$ accepted by the machine $M$ is the set of all binary strings whose number of $1$'s is a multiple of $3$. Thus, $L = \{\epsilon, 0, 00, 000, 111, 1101, \ldots\}$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty string in $\{0,1\}^*$.  Note that the empty string $\epsilon$ is accepted by $M$ because the start state of $M$ is one of its final states.

We claim that the given DFA $M$ also accepts the concatenation language $L^7$, i.e. that $L(M) = L^7$.  To prove this, we prove that $L=L^7$, by showing set inclusion in both directions. To show $L \subseteq L^7$, let $w \in L$.   Since $L$ contains the empty string $ \epsilon$, $w=w \epsilon \epsilon \epsilon \epsilon \epsilon \epsilon \in L^7$.

To prove the reverse inclusion $L \supseteq L^7$, consider any string $w=w_1 w_2 \ldots w_7 \in L^7$, where $ w_i \in L, \forall i$. Because the number of $1$'s in each $w_i$ is a multiple of $3$, the number of $1$'s in $w$ is also a multiple of $3$.  Hence, $w \in L$, as was to be shown. This proves (for the special case $k=3$) that $L=L^7$ and hence the language accepted by the given DFA is $L^7$.

It should be clear that this solution method works for any $k \ge 2$ - just replace the directed $3$-cycle in the DFA above with a directed $k$-cycle.